# react-i18next - No overload matches this call when `string` type specified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using `react-i18next` with `React` and `TypeScript`. If I try loading a property using a string literal and type inference, it works correctly. However if I specify the type of `string`, the error is thrown.

**i18n.ts**

```
import ns1 from './locales/en/translation.json';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from 'i18next';

export const defaultNS = 'ns1';

export const resources = {
  en: {
    ns1
  }
} as const;
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  lng: 'en',
  ns: ['ns1', 'ns2'],
  defaultNS,
  resources
});
```

**react-i18next.d.ts**

```
import { resources, defaultNS } from './i18n';

// react-i18next versions higher than 11.11.0
declare module 'react-i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    defaultNS: typeof defaultNS;
    resources: typeof resources['en'];
  }
}
```

**translation.json**

```
{
  "title": "Welcome to react using react-i18next",
  "description": {
    "part1": "To get started, edit <1>src/App.js</1> and save to reload.",
    "part2": "Switch language between english and german using buttons above."
  }
}
```

**Working code**

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const t = useTranslation().t;
const title = 'title';

// "Welcome to react using react-i18next"
console.log(t(title));
```

**No overload matches this call exception**

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const t = useTranslation().t;
const title: string = 'title';

// No overload matches this call exception
console.log(t(title));
```

How can I translate a `string` variable where the type is specified?

Comment: did you try with the latest i18next versino?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you are using type string, and that means it can be anything in there. I18next is using string literal types to check typing.

If you want types working in project, but sometimes use dynamic translation, at the moment you can cheat your way using Tagged Template Literal, as it does not work with type check right now:

```
t`key1.key2`;
```

[Based on i18 documentation](https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript#tagged-template-literal-react-i18next-only)

Another option is to just override typing on t function to any:

```
t<any>(`namespace:${dynamicString}`)
```